# Content Security Policy: Chrome logs connect-src error for image resource

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I set up Content Security Policy (report only) with the following policy:

```
report-uri https://my-company.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly?ngsw-bypass=true; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' data: https://s.gravatar.com;
```

In the Chrome dev console, the following error is logged:

> [Report Only] Refused to connect to
> 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/0346e37b7fed8cb32404a71dca932fdf?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Ffa.png'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com".

As you can see, the resource requested is an image, for which the url is whitelisted in the `img-src` directive of the CSP policy. However, Chrome reports that the error is a violation of the `connect-src` directive. I don't understand why the connect-src directive is evaluated instead of img-src, when the resource is clearly an image.

The same happens with fonts (https://fonts.gstatic.com) and the googletagmanager script (https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js), both cause a problem with `connect-src`, rather than `font-src` or `script-src`.

In Firefox and Safari, no errors are logged.

To add to the mystery, Chrome **does not report the error**, it only logs it to the console (no trace of the error on report-uri.com). Other (real) CSP errors are showing up on report-uri.com, so there is nothing wrong with the reporting setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's a service worker installed on the site, it might come into play when fetching images, scripts or fonts. In this case, the directive `connect-src` is used instead of the img/script/font-src directives.

The solution is to add the urls twice in the policy: once in the img/script/font-src directive, once in the connect-src directive.